# Пункт в анкетировании: Питание глазами сотрудников?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли сформулировано? *Питание глазами сотрудников.*

Comment: Покажите предложение целиком. Без этого нет однозначного понимания вопроса.

Comment: Да всё понятно, в Сети очень часто встречаются подобные выражения, например "компания глазами сотрудников". Здесь надо просто добавить: питание в школьной столовой глазами сотрудников.  Пример: http://we18.ru/wp-content/uploads/Анкетирование-«Питание-глазами-сотрудников»-.pdf

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Даже если это заголовок, выражающий взгляд неких сотрудников на проблемы питания, он крайне неудачен из-за двусмысленности ("употребление в пищу глаз сотрудников").

Comment: И зачем оригинальничать?. Вместо **Анкетирование «Питание глазами сотрудников»** (см. we18.ru/wp-content/uploads/ ) назвали бы **Анкетирование «Мнение сотрудников о питании».**